# How UniTaskVoid subscribe to an event?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

UniTask's documentation recommends to avoid "async void" and use UniTaskVoid instead. But I cannot find solution to subscribe to events

async void subscription

```
public class WindowGamePause : WindowView
{
    [SerializeField] private Button _restartGameButton;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _restartGameButton.onClick.AddListener(RestartGame); 
    }
    
    private async void RestartGame()
    {
        await Close();
        _gameManager.RestartGame();
    }
}
```

async UniTaskVoid subscription??

```
public class WindowGamePause : WindowView
{
    [SerializeField] private Button _restartGameButton;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _restartGameButton.onClick.AddListener(RestartGame); //What to do?
        _restartGameButton.onClick.AddListener(RestartGame().Forget); //Doesn't work correctly - the method fires on the line
    }
    
    private async UniTaskVoid RestartGame()
    {
        await Close();
        _gameManager.RestartGame();
    }
}
```

[UPDATE]

I found some solution. It works fine but I do something wrong because Rider says: "Closure can be eliminated: method has overload to avoid closure creation". And I don't have any ideas to avoid closures.

```
public class WindowGamePause : WindowView
{
    [SerializeField] private Button _restartGameButton;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _restartGameButton.onClick.AddListener(RestartGame);
    }
    
    private void RestartGame()
    {
        UniTask.Void( async () =>
        {
            await Close();
            _gameManager.RestartGame();
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can always simply add an in-between void like

```
private void Awake()
{
    _restartGameButton.onClick.AddListener(RestartGame);
}

private void RestartGame()
{
    RestartGame.Forget();
}

private async UniTaskVoid RestartGameAsync()
{
    await Close();
    _gameManager.RestartGame();
}
```

---

This basically could also be done with a lambda (but then you can't remove the listener in case it is ever needed)

```
_restartGameButton.onClick.AddListener(() => RestartGameAsync().Forget());
```

---

The problem is that in order to call `Forget` you already have to call the method and return a `UniTaskVoid` which will be immediately running.

Comment: Thanks. I know this approach but it looks like a crutch.

Comment: For example, you have 6 buttons - you need 12 methods to resolve. Looks like a bad practice

Comment: @AlekseiBurov seems pretty legit to me, as said you can use a lambda if you don't need to remove the callback which would reduce the methods back to 6 .. otherwise yes, tbh I prefer to have those explicit so you see better when exactly you enter async code

Comment: thanks for answer. I found some solution but with warnings. Could you check updates on the question?

Comment: @AlekseiBurov what does this do different from what I suggested? It is also using a lambda .. the same thing could be written again as two methods, one `void` and one `async UniTaskVoid` ...